# Why AJAX returns wrong result?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Sometimes function reload(); does't update the div's content. I call this function when clicking a button. Sometimes only one div won't update. Random div, on a random click. Sometimes first click won't work. The div content won't show any error, just a previous not updated number. and when I click the button again it updates and shows the correct one.

Example of the bug (Increasing the #number_input by one every time I click):
div content shows: **1, 2, 2, 4**
The problem is with those **2s**, **3** is missing. In database the number is correct.

I'm running a *local server (XAMPP)*. Same problem in *Firefox*, *Chrome* and *IE*.

No errors in *firebug* console. Requests are done correctly but returned value sometimes wrong. Usually only one array item is wrong, the one returned from the database.

Exactly same ajax code with different parameters (on complete) on different button works fine.

PS: *Changed my var names into shorter ones so they are eye friendly*

Button HTML:

```
<button id="xButton" class="btn btn-info">Text</button>
```

Button JS:

```
document.getElementById('xButton').onclick = function() {   
        var val = $('#number_input').val();
        if (val > 0) 
        {   
        var xx = 1;
        var yy = 1;
        properties(xx, yy, val); //this updates the database by current val + val. Works correctly. Values always updated, no errors there. Clean and simple code. No way this is the source of problem.

        number_input.value = 0;
        xButton.textContent = ("bla bla"); //just resets the text

        p1_reload();
        }
        }
```

jQuery:

```
    function reload() { 
        $.ajax({ 
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'example.php',
                cache: false,
                data: {reload: "action"},
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data) {

                var xres = new Array();
                xres = data;

document.getElementById("x1").textContent = xres[0];
document.getElementById("x2").textContent = xres[1];
document.getElementById("x3").textContent = xres[2];
document.getElementById("x4").textContent = xres[3];

//these two functions has not connection with the updated divs. They don't update or even read them. So, there shouldn't be any problems.
xFunction();
yFunction();
                }
            });
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['reload'])) {
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

    try
        {

    require_once("session.php");
    $auth_user = new xClass();
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];


    $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE user_id=:user_id LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    $xxx = $userRow['xxx'];
    $yyy = $userRow['yyy'];
    $zzz = $userRow['zzz'];


    $qqq = ($xxx * $yyy) + ($zzz + $yyy + $xxx);




$xres = array();
$xres[0] = $xxx;
$xres[1] = $yyy;
$xres[2] = $zzz;
$xres[3] = $qqq;



$result = json_encode($xres);

    echo $result;

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }


    }
}
```

Database return simple integer numbers. No triggers or decimal numbers.

jQuery version: 1.12.4 min.

Clicking every few second (no frequent clicking). Request and response complete in 10-38 ms.

Comment: Are you doing the ajax requests on the same trigger without delay? Because what might happen then, because you are using seperate ajax calls, is that your database has not actually finished updating yet before you get the results from the 2nd ajax. So the 2nd ajax might come back before the 1st one actually finished the php script.

Comment: It was the first thing I thought. The delay is sometimes a few seconds. No way database wouldn't update in a few seconds. Plus the requests are made locally, so no dealy (about 10-38 ms until values returned). I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and still test it. Make a second button just for reload. If the problem is still there, then you can be sure...

Comment: The element with id `number_input` doesn't exist, as well as the PHP class `xClass` and the Javascript functions `xFunction`, `yFunction`, `p1_reload` and `properties`.

Comment: They do exist. I didn't want to include all the function and the classes to since they has nothing to do with the problem. How do you think session, user id and generally dhow do I get a response from a database if those classes and functions don't exist?! As for the testing, I already did the same. Commented other functions to test it. Same result. I also got same result on other divs. same code. code looks correct to me. Have this problem for like a month. Today decided to resolve it.

Comment: hm... there are no obvious errors in this code, as far as I can see. So from my point of view the best would be to strip everything down to a minimum and test the little pieces. f.e: Is the result ok if you call 'example.php' directly, without ajax? Does it only happen when updating before, is that working correctly? ...

Comment: If it makes no difference, **remove it**. Provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Look like the problem occur when I'm calling multiple functions (in my case two) under button click event. I'm a bit new to ajax stuff but maybe "big" php function sending complete response while the last one wasn't completed yet. But I think ajax request does have an ID or something. And this doesn't explain why only one value of my response is incorrect. If you have an idea of what cause this problem please let me know.

Comment: At this present moment, in my opinion, you admited to have code that doesn't do anything there and you still have missing information (like, what comes from the database, why the class `xClass` is there and what does it do...). Also, we don't know the network activity you're seeing. And we can't run the code ourselves because you threw pieces of useless code around. Clean it up and then we can test the code ourselves and answer.

Comment: Really? Why should I include pieces of code which has nothing to do with the issue? Since database works fine why should I include this code? Why do you need my class since it does nothing but connecting to the database? I said the problem is that I call two ajax request when pressing a button. Why do you need extra code which is not even connected to the problem I'm facing? Okay maybe including a properties function would be better but as I stated it's the same ajax code with different code which has to be executed on complete. Just update other divs. Same code just different ids.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere in your  button js as well as jQuery source. Try replacing textContent with `innerHTML(for plain js)` or `html(JQuery)`After replacement it would be

`document.getElementById("x4").innerHTML = xres[3];` or as you are using jQuery  you could have `$("#x4").html(xres[3])`.

Comment: jQuery Source? As I remember I already tried innerHTML. The problem is not with button js because requests are always made. The problem is not with textconent because I always get a respond from the server but the data are wrong. Plus the content is always updated even though it's a wrong value.